# Content type load via PHP

Tags: 7, nodes

We load a specific node in our template.php file via `node_load()`, in the same way `<?php if ($content = render($page['content'])): ?>` is used for loading a block.

I have a content type (news), and I want to load this content type items on my template.php file. How can I do it?

Comment: As a note: you shouldn't be putting too much PHP logic in the theme. If you need more variables, consider building a small module.

Also, loading a specific node via template.php seems weird. Have you considered using Display Suite, Panels or Views for your needs?

Comment: I don't want use public module. It's impossible via PHP or API?

Comment: A module doesn't need to be public. There are many websites using Drupal, and a custom module that is not made public. What @askibinski says is true: Themes should not contain too much logic code, but only presentation code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the views module and [views_embed_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)